# How can I get hostapd_cli to work under sudo on debian stretch?

Tags: debian, command-line, sudo, hostapd, nrpe

I have a bash script that runs `hostapd_cli all_sta`, and the script executes successfully from the command line under both jessie and stretch.  The script also works when run under sudo on jessie but not on stretch.  On stretch the command times out with the error `'STA-FIRST' command timed out`.  When I invoke hostapd_cli under strace I see that it opens a socket file under `/tmp`:

```
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/tmp/wpa_ctrl_13552-1"}, 110) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/hostapd/wlan1"}, 110) = 0
```

As a test I temporarily modified the script and added a line:

```
echo "this is a test" >/tmp/test 2>/root/error
```

When the modified script runs under sudo, the file in `/tmp` is not created and no error is written to `/tmp/error`.

On my system, `/tmp` is not a tmpfs, just a plain old directory under `/` on an ext3 filesystem.  So root is unable to create a file under `/tmp` and there is ample space.

```
# df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       6.7G  5.1G  1.4G  80% /
```

And an `ls -ld /tmp` gives:

```
# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 4096 Jul 27 23:50 /tmp/
```

If I can figure out why `/tmp` can't be written to, I believe the hostapd_cli command will work.  What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was not working as expected was because `/tmp` was remapped by systemd to `/tmp/systemd-private-67fcab218d3d46bcb5092dd8a6d4789b-nagios-nrpe-server.service-lN2L1e/tmp`

The issue had nothing to do with sudo but the fact that sudo was executing as a plugin running under the nrpe daemon which in turn was configured to have a private `/tmp` under systemd.

To resolve I had set to:

```
systemctl stop nagios-nrpe-server
set PrivateTmp=false in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nagios-nrpe-server.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start nagios-nrpe-server
```